swiper слайдер не свайпится на андроиде
Вот HTML
<div class="slider swiper">
    <div class="slider_wrapper swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="slide swiper-slide">
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="slide swiper-slide">
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide_prev"></div>
<div class="slide_next"></div>

Вот JS
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
    const swiper = new Swiper('.slider', {
        loop: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.slide_next',
            prevEl: '.slide_prev',
        },
        keyboard: 
        {
            enabled: true,
            onlyInViewport: false,
        }
    });
});
});

Вот ссылка на действующий слайдер. https://maindenis.github.io/metafarm/index.html. Слайдер не свайпится на смартфоне. Как это исправить?

Проверил, свайпится всё.
